# N(th) Highest Salary Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I found a solution for finding the n(th) highest salary from the web :

```
SELECT * FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
           FROM Employee Emp2
           WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
           )
```

But I am unable to understand how the query is actually being executed, i.e. how the query is processing at each step, especially in the subquery where multiple alias of same table occur ->

```
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
```

And what is the comparison operator doing with this-

```
WHERE (N-1) = <subquery>
```

Can someone please help me out with it?

Comment: In Mangement Studio there is a option under `Query` called `Display Estimated Execution Plan` or `Ctrl-L`. Let that become your friend for questions like this. SQL-Server will show you have to query will be executed.

Answer (score 4):

The Nth Highest salary is the one where there are N-1 higher salaries
E.g. the highest salary has no higher salaries

Making the following change to the query should demonstrate how it works:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee Emp1
CROSS APPLY
           (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)) AS NHigher
           FROM Employee Emp2
           WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
           ) X;
```

Fiddle for [Sql Server here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc9c8/2)

Note however that most RDBMS allow `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` type restrictions, which will allow you to do retrieve the Nth row more efficiently with a plain `ORDER BY`.

e.g. In SQL Server 2012, to fetch the 2nd highest salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
ORDER BY SALARY DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

edited : this question is asking how to get n(th) highest salary or get top n(th) salary ?
 the examples says how to get n(th) salary for get top n(th) just change the line 2
 `WHERE emp.Salary =` to `WHERE emp.Salary >=` :D

there is one solution for this :

1. take Nth top salary
2. get the employees that have that salary

now you can implement it in witch way u like :

first solution grouping salary's :

```
SELECT * FROM Employee as emp
WHERE emp.Salary = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 t.Salary FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP N(th) e.Salary FROM Employee as e
        Group by e.Salary
        Order By e.Salary
    ) as t
    ORDER BY t.Salary DESC
)
```

second solution DISTINCT salarys :

```
SELECT * FROM Employee as emp
WHERE emp.Salary = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 t.Salary FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP N(th) e.Salary FROM Employee as e
        Order By e.Salary
    ) as t
    ORDER BY t.Salary DESC
)
```

Comment: The question was how does it work, not how to do it. Explain to the person how the queries are executed to give him a result. He wants to understand the method, not the solution